# How are the public and private keys stored and related on both client and server?

Tags: ssh, openssl

I have tried to match the public keys and private keys on both my client and server as well as the configuration files but cannot get my head around the mismatches. I can successfully connect to the server on ssh *despite* the mismatches. This is a bit worrying.

I will show exactly what is stored where.

Client: Mac
Server: Ubuntu (hosted on AWS)

Files on my local mac /Users/sm/.ssh directory

```
ls -la 
Sanjays-iMac:.ssh sm$ ls -la
total 24
drwx------   5 sm  staff   160 26 Nov 21:29 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 59 sm  staff  1888 26 Nov 21:29 ..
-rw-------   1 sm  staff  1696 26 Nov 20:49 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--@  1 sm  staff   451 26 Nov 20:50 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 sm  staff  1151 26 Nov 21:08 known_hosts
```

Files on my ubuntu server:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-19:~/.ssh$ ls -la
total 12
drwx------ 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Nov 26 14:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct 30 18:02 ..
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  391 May 25  2018 authorized_keys
```

Present working directory on Ubuntu:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-19:~/.ssh$ pwd
/home/ubuntu/.ssh
```

Contents of `authorized_keys` file on the server:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-19:~/.ssh$ cat authorized_keys 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAA....0g1bMv+p11K8MDH sanjaydev
```

(contents are chopped off for privacy reasons)

Similarly, there is a known_hosts file on my local server:

```
Sanjays-iMac:.ssh sm$ cat known_hosts
54.251.104.13 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLX..Xsb/RBY=
52.76.85.25 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTI....hAkfLOc5g=
ec2-13-127-241-121.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com,13.127.241.121 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXN....fu5Co4vYB0=
ec2-13-232-81-251.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com,13.232.81.251 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhL....nhNcRyfu5Co4vYB0=
35.154.168.85 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNo....NcRyfu5Co4vYB0=
13.126.30.42 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTIt....NcRyfu5Co4vYB0=
```

(contents are chopped off for privacy reasons)

Now my question is:

What should be equal to what?

I would think that the public key on the client should match with one of the entries inside the `authorised_keys` file on the server and the public key of the server should match with one of the entres in the `known_hosts` file on the client.

Unfortunately, when I manually try to match them they did not match fully (only first few characters match). It is important to note that the ssh connection still goes through without giving the `-i <pemfile>` on the command line.

Answer (score 6):

There are two kinds of keys: *Server* or *host* keys, which identify the server to the user, and *user* keys, which allow logging in.

The private host key of the server is stored in `/etc/ssh/`. The corresponding public key is automatically added (after a prompt) to `known_hosts` in `~/.ssh` on the client. The purpose of these keys is detect a man-in-the-middle (MITM) attack: If the host key suddenly changes when you type `ssh ...` as usual, and you know nothing has changed on the server, you should get suspicious.

Usually you don't have to concern yourself with the host keys, they are managed automatically.

User keys allow authentication without entering passwords. User keys are managed on the client: You have created a key pair consisting of your public key `id_rsa.pub` and your private key `id_rsa`. They are stored on the client under `~/.ssh`. The public key is not used, it's just stored there to be available when needed. You must manually add the public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for the corresponding user on the server. One key per line; if the `authorized_keys` file is empty, a copy (e.g. via `scp` and password) of `id_rsa.pub` is enough.

So in your case, the

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAA....0g1bMv+p11K8MDH sanjaydev
```

in the `authorized_keys` file on the Ubuntu server must be equal to your `id_rsa.pub` key on the Mac.

If it is equal and you still can't log in, something else is wrong.

Comment: ... and if you don’t like manually editing `authorized_keys`, `ssh-copy-id` can take care of it for you.

Comment: One advantage of editing `authorized_keys` manually is that while you are doing that, you'll also look at it and can verify that it contains all the keys it should (no more, and no less; and often enough I find a key that shouldn't be in there anymore). But yes, you can automate it.

Comment: Indeed, I like your point about taking the opportunity to check the keys which are already there! Good key hygiene is important.

Comment: What you conclude at the end is actually my question. Your statement: "the entry in the `authorised_keys` file on the Ubuntu must be equal to your `id_rsa.pub` on the Mac". Well they aren;t equal but I still am able to ssh successfully.  i also get a warning while connecting: `key_load_public: invalid format`. So perhaps the id_rsa.pub is corrupted. So as a summary my question is still open.

Comment: On the second sentence of your answer @dirkt: " The corresponding public key is automatically added (after a prompt) to known_hosts in ~/.ssh on the client.". When is this prompt received?

Comment: The prompt is received when the host key is not in `known_hosts`, or different from the key stored there. I don't now what goes on with the `key_load_public: invalid format` because I don't have enough information (are they mostly equal with a typo? Totally different? *Why* are they different? Because you made a mistake? etc.). You can debug via verbose flags with `ssh -v ...`, up to `-vvv`. You can also debug on the server side, if necessary. And all this information really **should** be in the question; I'm not able to guess unless you tell me.

Comment: @user30994+ you revealed on another answer you used `openssl rsa -pubout` to create the public key. That's wrong; OpenSSL uses very different format for public key than OpenSSH. Use `ssh-keygen -y -f privatefile` if you need to (re)generate the public key for OpenSSH.

Answer (score 3):

### Key Format Fun

From your comments listed on other answers, it looks like you may have a key format problem.

It is true that a cryptographic key created with one standardized program is the same mathematically as a key generated in another.  However, a given cryptographic protocol expects keys in a given format.

**Converting Keys**

- openssl to ssh keys

Keys generated in `openssl` and outputted in PEM format can be converted to ssh format using the `ssh-keygen` program.

`ssh-keygen -i -m pem -f key.pem`

- ssh keys to PEM

Keys generated using ssh-keygen can be converted to PEM format:

`ssh-keygen -e -m pem -f id_rsa.pub`

- PGP to ssh keys

PGP keys generated in GPG can be converted to ssh format using the `--export-ssh-key` option:

`gpg --export-ssh-key <keyid>`

**Location of keys**

As listed in other answers, the remote system requires the public key stored in ssh format in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.  And the local system requires that the private key is:

- Stored as id_rsa in `~/.ssh`

or

- Supplied using the `ssh -i` option

or

- Added to the ssh agent using `ssh-add`

or

- Added to the ssh agent using GPG's `sshcontrol` file

**Comparing Public Keys**

In order to compare public keys, those keys must be in the same format.  Otherwise, the keys won't look the same, even though they are the same objects mathematically.  So, since you've indicated that you generated your ssh public key using `openssl` in PEM format, the public key is probably not going to look the same as the one stored in the server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

PEM format keys look like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAr/CvdghgkYT1Z38d
...
NlBcCYnrjvfFAj5HQydWc9CfP02rdtCIewIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

SSH Public Keys look like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...voZypjC/Y2UFwJie...t20Ih7
```

PGP Public Keys look like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

mQENBFN/ZjIBCADad3mv...
...
nE42ZvKt632ZAQ==
=EKbR
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

So, make sure you are comparing keys in the same format.

Answer (score 1):

The `known_hosts` is from the server's sshd key - in `/etc/ssh/*pub`

Answer (score 0):

The `authorized_keys` file should have a line containing the contents of `id_rsa.pub`, and the `known_hosts` file should have a line containing the server's host key. (The server usually stores its host keys in a file under `/etc/ssh/`.)

Also, `id_rsa` should kind of match `id_rsa.pub` in the sense that they need to be a key pair, but unless you mangle it manually, that's how ssh-keygen always places them.

Comment: I did not have an id_`rsa.pub` so I generated a public key using 
`openssl rsa -in mykey.pem -pubout`

Comment: @user30994 Hmm? Your question clearly lists your `id_rsa.pub` with a matching `id_rsa`?

Comment: I presume it is a paired public key as I generated it from the private key that is stored in id_rsa. Is there a way to confirm if the public key is matching with the private key?

Comment: @user30994 ... You used `openssl` to create a public key from a private key.  However, `ssh` usually doesn't generate PEM format keys by default.  So, you may have better luck finding your "match" by comparing the PEM public key in `ssh` format ... `ssh-keygen -i -m pem -f id_rsa.pem` ... **Please add your key generation process to your question**

Comment: @RubberStamp: ssh-keygen mostly did create OpenSSL-style ('legacy') PEM _private_ key files except for 7.8 up (released 3 months ago and not yet widespread), or ed25519 or `-o` since 6.5 in 2014. But the _public_ key format used by OpenSSH has always been totally different from the OpenSSL format, so always need(ed) `ssh-keygen -y -f private` to generate OpenSSH public key.